# How to take javascript variable in php mysql query?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am new to Javascript and PHP. Can anyone let me know how to take javascript variable in php variable and I want to use that php variable in MySQL query to fetch the data from MySQL database. Whether it is possible to take javascript variable directly in MySQL query?

I have tried but I am unable to get the result. I have attached code below

```
<script>
var baccount = document.getElementById('accountid');
var bacc = baccount.value;
</script>

<?php 

$abcd = '"+bacc+"';

$quer=mysql_query("SELECT * from fpay_user where account_id='$abcd'");


$result=mysql_fetch_array($quer);

$rbal = $result['balance'];

echo $rbal;

?>
```

Comment: you could use javascript to reload the page with a querystring, the variable being part of the querystring or, more commonly, use ajax to send a request to the php script and thus to the db

Answer (score 0):

It is not as simple as that. Javascript runs in the browser (the client) and php runs on the web server (the host). These are two different computers. To pass data from the client to the host, you can make an an http request from javascript to a specific url on the server. When the server sends its response you can process it in javascript again.

An example (using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) would be:

```
<script>
  // success will be called when the server sent a response.
  function success(result) {
    // result.responseJSON is a javascript object: { balance: 1234 }
    let balance = result.responseJSON.balance
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/script.php',
    data: {
        bacc: baccount.value
      },
    success: success,
    dataType: 'json'
  });
</script>
```

In php you can fetch the passed value, do your query and return the result:

```
<?php
  // get the passed value
  $abcd = $_GET['bacc'];

  // do the query SAFELY. See explanation below.
  $quer = mysql_query("SELECT * from fpay_user where account_id='" . mysql_escape_string($abcd) . "'");
  $result=mysql_fetch_array($quer);

  // Now return the result as json string
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  // This will encode the result as: "{balance: 1234}"
  echo json_encode($result);
```

One *very* important thing. You should always sanitize the received values with something like `mysql_escape_string`. If you do not do that, your software is susceptible to SQL injection. I have added this function call to your example.

Comment: There are two script: javascript and php. Which script? Which line?

Comment: In javascript I am getting error. I have given proper path to script.php but I am still getting error in '/path/to/script.php', this line.

Comment: I am getting error as Uncaught syntaxterror : missing ) after agrument list at the line data: { in javascript program.

Comment: I see. Sorry about that. I fixed the code in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. The error which I got previously has been solved, but I am getting error as cannot read property 'balance' of undefined in the line, let balance = result.responseJSON.balance. I am getting output in php program [ echo json_encode($result); ] but I am unable to get it in javascript.

Comment: I am able to solve the above problem. Using document.write I can get the balance in browser, but I am unable to use that balance outside the function success(result){ .... }.

Comment: That is correct and it is not possible in any other way. The value is only available after javascript has taken the value of the bank account number, sent the request to the server and processed the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

You need understand the difference of client language and server language.

In your code, JavaScript is executed in browser, while the PHP is executed in your server. To make the PHP knows what happened in the client, your client must send this information to the server, through query string, form post or raw data post.

For your case, you can send an Ajax request from the JavaScript to the server, (using native XMLHttpRequest, or jQuery)

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: {bacc:value},
});
```

Then your PHP can access it via $_POST["bacc"]

Do understand that although you could write it in the same file (which is a bad practice), they are executed in different place (client or server)